# Usage of Parameters.Add not working

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, visual-studio

I have a C# program developed in VS 2010 that generates a report by reading parameters supplied from a stored procedure in SQL server. I have two ways of calling the parameters:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SponsorID", strSponsorID);
```

This works perfectly fine with no issue. However when I tried to use a different method like this:

```
paramFields.Add("SponsorID", (strSponsorID == "" ? "ALL" : strSponsorID));
```

It throws an error claiming:

> the parameters could not be supplied.

Note: `Paramfields` is a variable that I declared.

```
SortedList paramFields = new SortedList();
```

May I know what is the possible issue?

Comment: what is your paramFields? is it a list of ReportParameter?

Comment: what is the Typeof ParamFields? also you havent given @ when using paramFields.Add("SponsorID", (strSponsorID == "" ? "ALL" : strSponsorID));

Comment: It's a sorted list variable

Comment: SortedList paramFields = new SortedList();

Comment: @CookieMonster Can you include the code you use to declare paramFields?

Comment: I edited the post

Comment: Can you also include the code that uses paramFields? I'm not sure there is enough context here to know what the issue is.

Comment: the second line uses paramFields.

Comment: Basically paramFields.Add just couldn't capture the parameter in stored procedure.

Comment: @CookieMonster Is that the line that is causing the error "parameters could not be supplied"? Or is it another line where the paramFields is used by a method call?

Comment: The error could also be caused by a data type issue. Your parameter is named `...ID` which is usually a numeric value like an integer but you pass `"ALL"` which is a string.

Comment: Basically when I used the paramField.add to call the parameter, it causes the error. When I replaced it with command.Parameter.addwithvalue , it works fine.

Comment: It's amazing how requesting for help in SO can gather downvotes easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not try something like this with your `AddWithValue`?

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SponsorID", string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strSponsorID) ? 
                                              "ALL" : strSponsorID);
```

Or even simpler if just NULL checking enough:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SponsorID", strSponsorID ?? "ALL");
```

Although specify the type directly and use the `Value` property is more better than `AddWithValue`:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@SponsorID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value
            = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strSponsorID) ?
            "ALL" : strSponsorID;
```

However you need to add `using System.Data;` to your `using` directives first.

[Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: I understand but why wouldn't my second method work?

Comment: You may want to read [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes. I was just looking for this link to update my answer.

Comment: @S.Akbari Thanks for the explanation.